# What is the template body for an API Gateway to pass the complete $context.authorizer.claims to the Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to make the Cognito work with a Lambda function associated with an API Gateway. And I would like to get the claims complete object passed to the Lambda function.

This is what I've got as the template body to pass the email address from claims to the Lambda function:

```
{
  "email": "$context.authorizer.claims.email"
}
```

But I'm looking for something like this:

```
{
  "claims": "$context.authorizer.claims"
}
```

Obviously, this does not work (it will return an empty string as for `claims`). And I think it's because `claims` is an object. So how can I pass an object (here it would be `claims`) to the Lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `$context.authorizer.claims` returns `null` in the mapping template ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference)). You'll have to use [Lambda Proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) for that.